# rsync is not preserving file timestamps with the 'a' option when writing to cifs mount

Tags: rsync

My Ubuntu 22.04 VM (on my synology nas) preserves file timestamps when writing to it's local filesystem, but not when writing to a cifs mount (on the nas).  This causes it to re-grab the non-preserved files the next times it runs again.

My laptop pop_os 22.04 will preserve file timestamps on the same cifs mount.

Both are running the same versions of rsync and cifs-tools.

Mounts listed here:

vm:
`//192.168.86.37/files on /home/rob/synner type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=rob,uid=1000,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.86.37,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`

laptop:
`//192.168.86.37/files on /home/rob/synner type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=rob,uid=1000,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.86.37,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,closetimeo=5)`

mount command used on both:
`mount -t cifs -o username=rob,password=<redacted>,uid=1000 //192.168.86.37/files /home/rob/synner`

rsync command being used:
`/usr/bin/rsync -avz --progress root@kp3:/home/backup/ /home/rob/synner/hosting_backups/kp3/`

Edit: with more info..

When the VM looks at remote (kp3), along with new files, it will also re-download files it has already grabbed, but will timestamp everything with the time it's actually grabbing the files, so it will just do it all over again the next day when it runs.

I've also added 'noserverino' to the mount command on the VM to get rid of the 'serverino' portion in it's mount statement with no difference.

Comment: Please see the answer I just added, which has the cause for the issue on Synology devices and the solution: https://serverfault.com/a/1153181/378893

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue (`rsync` silently not preserving timestamps) when trying to copy ~60 GB of jpg/mp4 files from a **src:** exfat mount to a **dst:** cifs mount.

At first I wondered if it was the source filesystem causing issues but it turned out to be an issue with either my cifs client or server versions (of the binaries/libs installed).

What helped me in the end was to force the smb/cifs client version to `mount.cifs -o vers=2.0`.

After this `rsync` was able to preserve the destination filesystem timestamps as expected when using `--archive, -a` or `--times, -t`.

Here are the smb/cifs versions that were causing me issues.

```
# client
smbclient -V
Version 4.13.13-Debian

apt-cache policy smbclient
smbclient:
  Installed: 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5

# server
smbd -V
Version 4.9.5-Debian

apt-cache policy samba
samba:
  Installed: 2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1
```

I came across [Ubuntu bug #2007055](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/2007055) which gave me the idea to try downgrading the client protocol from automatically chosen `SMB3_11` to `SMB2_02`. I'm *guessing* with latest versions the bug goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I've started diving into this issue upon hitting it recently. I've updated the [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2007055) @Kyle linked here with lots of details, and have a ticket open with Synology. Here's a quick summary of the current state:

My current assessment is that this is a bug on the Synology server side that is triggered by the pattern of SMB messages sent from specific clients. I've tried a simple `cp -p` operation with the latest Ubuntu 20/22/23 and Arch as clients. The Ubuntu 20 and 22 clients repro the issue, while Ubuntu 23 and Arch do not. Windows also does not when doing a command line `copy`.

Further, the problem does not reproduce when replacing the *server* with TrueNAS (13.0-U3.1) or the latest Ubuntu 22.

Examining the network captures during the `cp -p` shows that the clients that trigger the issue wrap their SetInfo SMB message with create file/close file SMB messages. The clients that do not trigger the issue do not.

[image: Network capture comparison]

While I don't think Ubuntu 20/22 are doing anything wrong, I could see the extra create file/close file messages causing the Synology server to lose track of the fact that the last operation on the file was to set the mod time, and that when the file is closed its mod time does not need to be updated. Then when the final file close message comes in, the mod time is incorrectly updated (because the file had bytes written to it before the mod time was set).

I *really* wish I could run strace on the synology box, because that would show the file accesses and modtime changes being done by smbd. Unfortunately, strace is no longer included with synogear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are hitting can be fixed by changing a setting on the Synology NAS. In the SMB Advanced Settings "Others" tab, check "Synchronize data to drive immediately upon SMB client request".

[image]

This preference controls the SMB `strict sync` configuration value. It was [changed from False to True 6 years ago in Samba 4.7.0](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/commit/ed483d8e570700a303e11bc03d6250cd0ae4aaed).

Synology devices still default this value to False though. Unfortunately, the False value causes [this Samba bugfix that helped with correct modtimes](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/merge_requests/1210/diffs?commit_id=945158c7652bd0580828fb620afc722bc8a05967) to not work.

(That bugfix does not work when `strict sync` is disabled, because `smbd_smb2_flush_send` checks `lp_strict_sync` and returns early instead of setting the `smbd_smb2_flush_done` callback to run; `smbd_smb2_flush_done` is where one of the modtime-related fixes was made.)

I've double validated that it is this setting that makes the difference. Setting it to True on the Synology device causes modtimes to be preserved. Setting it to False on an Ubuntu VM that was preserving modtimes causes it to stop.

I passed this info on to Synology, and they've said they will fix this issue in a future DSM release. I also [mentioned the issue with the Samba bugfix for modtimes to the Samba project](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/merge_requests/1210?commit_id=945158c7652bd0580828fb620afc722bc8a05967) in case they are interested.

Alternatively, you can update your clients to a later Ubuntu to send "cleaner" SMB requests as detailed [in my other answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1152188/378893). But changing the setting on the Synology server is a more powerful and robust solution, imho.